# Getting welcome message at root with Phusion Passenger on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: node.js, nginx, passenger, ubuntu-14.04

I'm getting the Welcome to Nginx message when I point to the root of the domain (Phusion Passenger running on Ubuntu 14.04).

Example:

http://www.example.com -> nginx message

http://www.example.com/bob -> application

On 12.04, it works exactly as it's supposed to where root goes to the application.

Comment: This question appears to belong on another site in the Stack Exchange network because its not about programming. Perhaps [Super User](https://www.superuser.com/) or [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/).